# Parameter type not assignable in printjs

Tags: angular, printjs

I'm trying to use `printJS` in Angular, and it was Ok until I had to use the multiple images feature. I was getting a error of `printJS` is not defined, and after searching for solution for the import I got here: https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/issues/154.

Tried the solution of import. But now I have this problem with the initialization of `printJS`

What I'm trying to do:

```
//import
import printJSer from 'print-js'
...
// create a list first with the URLs
listImpressao.push(fileURL)
...
// try to print all images
if(tipo=='image'){
   printJSer({printable: listImpressao, type:'image'})
}
```

It gives the following error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ printable: string[]; type: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Configuration'.
>     Type '{ printable: string[]; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Configuration'.
>       Types of property 'printable' are incompatible.
>         Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

What I need to do to stop this error? I can't `ng build` the app because of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library latest version has an updated TypeScript interface.
https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/commit/3a3c60422a184560c07715eed0ee8d70f36ea393

The printable parameter can now be a string or array.

Just run `npm update print-js` and you should no longer get that error.